# Time limit exceeded error C++

Tags: c++, vector, iostream

I'm programming in C++ some problems in an automated platform an it gives me time limit exceeded, I tested the code in terminal and I don't know why it doesn't stop waiting for numbers and I put a limit for n numbers in a while loop. It should stop when I enter n numbers. Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int n;
    while (cin >> n){
        vector<int> v(n);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            cin >> v[i];
            bool unique = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j){

                if (v[i] == v[j]){
                    unique = false;
                    j = 1;
                }
            }
            if (unique)
            ++count;
        }
            cout << count << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `j = 1;`?  What's that for?

Comment: if you hit a duplicate element you set `j = 1` and may keep looping forever...

Comment: Setting `j=1;` in your inner loop won't help in cases when `i` >= 3.

Comment: Is that a problem on UVA online?

Comment: @Aleksandar No, from UPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stalling the program with the following statement in the inner `for` loop:

```
j = 1;
```

I think you can safely remove that line and it *should* start working as intended, perhaps changing the inner loop to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i && unique; ++j) { ... }
```

Comment: I only had to delete j = 1 :)

Comment: His method is faster, as you break out of the loop when you get a non unique element.